# How can I convert request file to base64 encoded string in node js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, file-upload, base64, adonis.js

I using adonis.js

I try code like this :

```
import { HttpContextContract } from '@ioc:Adonis/Core/HttpContext'
const FileReader = require('file-reader');

export default class MyController {
  public async test({ request, response }: HttpContextContract) {;
    const fileToBase64 = async (file) =>
      new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const reader = new FileReader()
        reader.readAsDataURL(file)
        reader.onload = () => resolve(reader.result)
        reader.onerror = (e) => reject(e)
      })

    const file = request.file('files')
    const imageStr = await fileToBase64(file)
    return imageStr
  }
}
```

But if I run the function, there exist error like this :

```
invalid glob pattern: undefined
```

How can I solve this error?

The result reques.file('files') :

```
{
    "fieldName": "files[]",
    "clientName": "test.xlsx",
    "size": 8212,
    "type": "application",
    "extname": "xlsx",
    "subtype": "vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet",
    "state": "consumed",
    "isValid": true,
    "validated": true,
    "errors": [],
    "meta": {}
}
```

Comment: The module you're using, `file-reader`, doesn't do what you think it does. For reading files in Node.js, use [`fs`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html).

Comment: @robertklep I had try it. But it using path. My case is not use path but request uploaded file like above

Comment: Why aren't you using any of the provided functionality that Adonis.js offers for [file uploads](https://docs.adonisjs.com/guides/file-uploads)? Like move it to a local folder, then read it using `fs`?

Comment: @robertklep Yes you are right. But my case is not using local folder. The Uploaded files are sent to a file server/an external api

Comment: https://docs.adonisjs.com/guides/file-uploads#tmppath

Comment: @robertklep What do you mean?

Comment: File uploads are stored in a temporary location, you should be able to use that location to read the file data using `fs`.

Comment: @robertklep Like this : `request.file('files').tmpPath` Right? I try it and it works. But the problem is it removes the file extension in the filename

Comment: The file data in your question is showing the `clientName` (and the extension).

Comment: @robertklep Thank you very much. I had try it and it works